# Madgwick IMU algorithm: does magnetometer adds any value only for the pitch value?

Tags: algorithm, filtering, pitch

I am building a clinometer for my bicycle using the Madgwick IMU algorithm implemented in some AHRS libraries. I have the doubt if the magnetometer adds any correction/precission for the y axis (pitch) or I can do without it (with a 6 axis IMU) without loosing precission.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After taking some time for reading I can answer myself: yes,magnetometer adds better precission, but we can also do without it, specially with Mahony filter.  Some useful readings:

- http://www.olliw.eu/2013/imu-data-fusing/
- https://forum.pololu.com/t/madgwick-mahony-ahrs-code-for-altimu-9-and-10-sensors/19293
- https://learn.adafruit.com/ahrs-for-adafruits-9-dof-10-dof-breakout/sensor-fusion-algorithms

In particular, I quote from last link:
"Mahony is more appropriate for very small processors, whereas Madgwick can be more accurate with 9DOF systems at the cost of requiring extra processing power (it isn't appropriate for 6DOF systems where no magnetometer is present, for example)."

Regards.